Tychonian Universe
I am struggling with calculations that are required in a sub-section of a paper that I am writing: The retrograde motion of a Tychonian Universe from a Martian frame of reference.
I have found the Euler-Lagrange equations for the below Lagrange equations:
$$ L_{ES} = \frac{1}{2}m_E\dot r_{ES}^2 + \frac{Gm_EM_S}{r_{ES}} $$
$$ L_{MS} = \frac{1}{2}m_M\dot r_{MS}^2 + \frac{Gm_MM_S}{r_{MS}} $$
to be for $L_{ES}$:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dL_{ES}}{d\dot{r}})-\frac{dL_{ES}}{dr}=0 $$
$$\frac{d}{d\dot{r}}(\frac{1}{2}m_E\dot{r}^2_{ES}+\frac{Gm_EM_S}{r_{ES}})$$
$$=m_e\dot{r}_{ES}$$
$$\to \frac{d}{dt}(m_E\dot{r}_{ES})=M_E\ddot{r}_{ES}\frac{d}{dr}(\frac{1}{2}m_E\dot{r}^2_{ES}+\frac{Gm_EM_S}{r_{ES}}) = -\frac{Gm_EM_S}{r_{ES}^2}$$
$$=$$
$$ m_E\ddot{r}_{ES}+\frac{Gm_EM_S}{r_{ES}^2}=0 $$
but I cannot seem to use these and a coordinate transformation to find: $$r_{ME}=-r_{ES}(t)+r_{MS}(t)$$ to plot a graph that resembles image 1?


Please don't ask a new question if the old one was closed. Instead, edit the old one and try to reopen.

You can’t get what you want from those Lagrangians. Either you don’t know how to write vectors in MathJax or you don’t understand that the $\dot r^2$ has to be $\dot{\mathbf r}^2$ or you don’t understand that those aren’t the same thing.


Am not familiar with MathJax


It's similar to LaTeX.

A link to the MathJax tutorial is in Step 1 of the instructions for writing a question. You cannot expect anyone on this site to assume that $r$ is a vector. It’s a radial coordinate.

LOL, but you understood...

Yes, but you should not have expected anyone to. You didn’t even write “Here $r$ means (in the kinetic term) a vector because I don’t know how to write vectors.”

I didn't I am just not familiar with the software. I have only come to ask for help and guidance which I feel I am not getting in this conversation so unless you have something useful to add about my work please leave quietly

@phy_theo Please stay polite. Note that questions are meant to be useful for a broader audience, i.e. other members and potential future readers with a similar problem. Hence, questions (and answers) must be self-contained, must define and explain everything necessary (and/or include references). What I want to point out is: Some members will ask you to clarify, edit etc., which might not be related to your question in the first place, but rather to improve the overall quality.


but I cannot seem to use these and a coordinate transformation to find: $$r_{ME}=-r_{ES}(t)+r_{MS}(t)$$ to plot a graph that resembles image [1]

The problem seems to be that you are considering only the radial coordinate, but you need to treat the positions as vectors, a la:
$$
\vec r_{ME}=-\vec r_{ES}(t)+\vec r_{MS}(t)\;.
$$
You can chose one of either the earth or mars as being in a fixed plane of rotation, and so reduce one of the position vectors to two degrees of freedom, but the other you will have to treat as a fully three-dimensional vector.
You will also need to have some information about the starting positions of the earth and mars in three dimensional coordinates.


I have found the Euler-Lagrange equations for the below Lagrange equations:
$$ L_{ES} = \frac{1}{2}m_E\dot r_{ES}^2 + \frac{Gm_EM_S}{r_{ES}} $$

One problem with your use of this equation (and the similar one for Mars) is that you are using the symbol $r_{ES}$ in the potential energy term as the magnitude of a vector, but the $r_{ES}$ in the former term should be a vector, not just the magnitude of the vector. As written, it looks like you are ignoring the angular component of the velocity. This is because
$$
\dot{\vec{r}} = \hat r \dot r + \dot{\hat r} r = \hat r \dot r + \hat \theta \dot \theta r
$$
so
$$
|\dot{\vec{r}}|^2 = \dot r^2 + r^2\dot\theta^2\;.
$$
This means that your equations of motion should read:
$$
m\ddot r - mr\dot\theta^2 + GMm/r^2 = 0\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(mr\dot\theta\right) = 0\;.
$$
So you can see, for example, that uniform circular motion with a fixed radius $r=R$ and fixed angular velocity $\dot\theta =\Omega$ is a possible solution to Eq. (1) where
$$
\Omega = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{R^3}}\;.
$$

Do you think that it could be taken in a two dimensional plane rather than three? And how would this effect?

I think that could be a good way to start understanding the issues involved. E.g., look at a toy problem where both planets are in a single plane and only their distance from the sun and starting positions differ.

@phy_theo From https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/marsfact.html the mean orbital inclination of Mars is ~1.85°, which isn't much, so it's ok to ignore in a rough approximation. OTOH, even in ancient times people knew that the path of Mars could deviate by several degrees from the ecliptic.

Here's a plot of the ecliptic latitude of Mars, spanning a few years, with a 30 day time step. Data courtesy of JPL Horizons. https://i.sstatic.net/rUbz6CFk.png
